# Не работает @Autowired при взятии бина из другого модуля

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, модульность

Имею следующую структуру проекта:[image: структура проекта]

(Модуль HMD-model пока не используется).

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servler.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="controller,
                                        serv,
                                        service.*"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**DeveloperController.java**

```
package controller;


import model.Developer;
import serv.DevService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import service.impl.DeveloperServiceImpl;

@Controller
public class DeveloperController {

    private DevService devService;

//    private DeveloperServiceImpl developerServiceImpl;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "/index";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "developer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView developer() {
        return new ModelAndView("developer", "command", devService.getDeveloper());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addDeveloper", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("mvc-dispatcher") Developer developer,
                             ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("id", developer.getId());
        model.addAttribute("name", developer.getName());
        model.addAttribute("specilaty", developer.getSpecialty());
        model.addAttribute("experience", developer.getExperience());

        return "result";
    }

    @Autowired
    public DeveloperController(DevService devService/*, DeveloperServiceImpl developerServiceImpl*/) {
        this.devService = devService;
//        this.developerServiceImpl = developerServiceImpl;
    }
}
```

Где `DevService.java` и `DeveloperService.java` отличаются только именами и модулем, в котором они расположены.

**DevService.java**

```
package serv;

import model.Developer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DevService{
    public Developer getDeveloper(){
        Developer dev = new Developer();
        dev.setExperience(3);
        dev.setName("fname");
        dev.setId(1);
        dev.setSpecialty("lname");
        return dev;
    }
}
```

**Developer.java**

```
package model;

public class Developer {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String specialty;
    private int experience;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSpecialty() {
        return specialty;
    }

    public void setSpecialty(String specialty) {
        this.specialty = specialty;
    }

    public int getExperience() {
        return experience;
    }

    public void setExperience(int experience) {
        this.experience = experience;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Developer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", specialty='" + specialty + '\'' +
                ", experience=" + experience +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Данный код работает как надо, но, если снять комментарии в `DeveloperController.java` (то есть попытаться взять бин через `@Autowired` из другого модуля), то будет следующая ошибка:

[image: ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

Надо упаковать модуль в jar file и поместить его в локальный репозитарий посредством

```
mvn install:install-file
```

Смотри [здесь](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) как это делать. В `pom.xml` надо указать артифакт в качестве зависимости с областью видимости по умолчанию, т.е. `compile`.

[`NoClassDefFoundError`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) возникает в случае, если требуемый класс отсутствует при явном обращении во время выполнения. Это случается из-за того, что jar файл, который должен получаться из модуля при построении проекта отсутствует в целевой директории `lib` после построения главного модуля. Чтобы не копировать туда этот файл вручную, предлагается описанная выше процедура.

Comment: А разве 'mvn clean install' не выполняет данное действие? Я выполнил операцию [от сюда](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html), но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Так же в (HMD-view)pom.xml в <dependency> на HMD-controller дописал '<scope>compile</scope>'. Запускаю через tomcat -> local.